# Open two videos simultaneously using open cv? 2nd started abit later

Tags: python, opencv, asynchronous, image-processing, video-capture

I need to trigger a video play when a specific condition is true in my original video

Example:
I have a video playing using open CV.
During that video when a certain condition is true, I want another video to pop up and also start playing.

Given that the first video will continue playing without any problem.

This doesn't work,
using:

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(path)
while(cap.isOpen()):
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    if(condition):
        cap2=cv2.VideoCapture(path2)
        while(cap2.isOpen()):
            ret2,frame2=cap2.read()
            cv2.imshow("2nd video",frame2)
cv2.imshow('1st video',frame)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize both `VideoCapture` classes before the `while` loop.

```py
import cv2

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture("/Movies/B/ex1.mp4")
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture("/Movies/B/ex2.mp4")
```

Assume your `condition` is:

- play second video after first 5 frame of the the first video.
- Therefore I initialize the `count` variable

  - ```py
    count = 0
    ```
- Then check if whether the first video is opened, and play.

  - ```py
    while cap1.isOpened():
         ret1, frm1 = cap1.read()
         if ret1:
              cv2.imshow("frm1", frm1)
              cv2.waitKey(1)
         else:
             break
         count += 1

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    ```
- Now we will add our `condition`. Before we apply our condition criteria, we will set the second frame to `None`. If the condition is set, then get the input from the `cap2` variable

  - ```py
    while cap1.isOpened():
        ret1, frm1 = cap1.read()

        if ret1:
            # condition
            if count > 5:
                if cap2.isOpened():
                    _, frm2 = cap2.read()

            if frm2 is not None:
                cv2.imshow("frm2", frm2)
                cv2.waitKey(3)

            if frm1 is not None:
                cv2.imshow("frm1", frm1)
                cv2.waitKey(3)

         count += 1

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    ```

Output:

---

[image]

Please note that you don't have to use `cv2.waitKey(1)`. I used it to check whether my code is working or not.

Code

---

```py
import cv2

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture("b/b19.mp4")
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture("b/b22.mp4")

count = 0

frm2 = None

while cap1.isOpened():
    ret1, frm1 = cap1.read()

    if ret1:
        # condition
        if count > 5:
            if cap2.isOpened():
                _, frm2 = cap2.read()

        if frm2 is not None:
            cv2.imshow("frm2", frm2)
            cv2.waitKey(3)

        if frm1 is not None:
            cv2.imshow("frm1", frm1)
            cv2.waitKey(3)

    count += 1

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Second Option

---

You can also use `FileVideoStream` class for speeding up the video encoding, decoding, and displaying operations, by using Queue structure. As a result, `FileVideoStream` concurrently handles all the operations. Where `VideoCapture` class blocks the entire-application during frame encoding, decoding, or displaying.

```py
import cv2
from imutils.video import FileVideoStream

cap1 = FileVideoStream("b/b19.mp4").start()
cap2 = FileVideoStream("b/b22.mp4").start()

count = 0

frm2 = None

while cap1.more():
    frm1 = cap1.read()

    if count > 5:
        if cap2.more():
            frm2 = cap2.read()

    if frm2 is not None:
        cv2.imshow("frm2", frm2)
        cv2.waitKey(3)

    if frm1 is not None:
        cv2.imshow("frm1", frm1)
        cv2.waitKey(3)
    count += 1

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort for this problem, but with this solution what happens is the first video is paused until the 2nd video finishes. The requirement was the first video also continues to play when the 2md video pops up, an asynchronous solution. Really hoping for a solution, It's been a month I'm trying this. Looking forward for a reply.

Comment: I understand your concern now. I've tested and updated my answer.

Comment: It worked, just one last issue is ...after the 2nd video closes the speed(frame rate) of the first video increases like it's in fast forward is there a particular reason for that?